# How to find the multiple barcodes in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning

[image: This is the image having 3 barcodes[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVumZ.jpg)The following python code finds only one barcode in an image. I need to find more than one barcodes that are present in an image, any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
help = "path to the image file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ddepth = cv2.cv.CV_32F if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.CV_32F
gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=-1)

gradient = cv2.subtract(gradX, gradY)
gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)

blurred = cv2.blur(gradient, (9, 9))
(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)


kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations = 4)
closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations = 4)

cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
print(len(cnts))
#c = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
c = max(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea)

rect = cv2.minAreaRect(c)
box = cv2.cv.BoxPoints(rect) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)

cv2.drawContours(image, [box], -1, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Post your input and output image so others can test your code.

Comment: Also, it'd be nice, if you state the source, when you copy-paste code from elsewhere: https://github.com/sayands/opencv-implementations/blob/master/Barcode-Detector/detect_barcode.py

Comment: Sorry mate, its the same source you have linked, https://github.com/sayands/opencv-implementations/blob/master/Barcode-Detector/detect_barcode.py,

Comment: Now, can you please help me with the issue?

Comment: You need to loop over your contours, if you have more than one. I suggest you display your closed image to see that your threshold has not removed all the others or made it into only one. Why do you get the gradient edges? Why not just blur horizontally or use a horizontal morphology kernel to connect the barcodes into one connected region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The most important assumption I make is that the bar codes are aligned horizontally.**

`find_rectangles` is modified from [OpenCv Squares example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/squares.py). We use that to get our candidate contours. Then we group contours, processing in order by x. We can only add to a group if current contour is close enough, has a similar height in its center and has a similar height to the group's last added countour.

Finally, we check the smallest contour area in each group and estimate the amount of bars as that area over total group area. We discard any groups that have less than 10 bars.

We are left with groups that should be bar codes, all that is left is to draw the rectangle over the original image.

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

def get_center(contour):
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / max(M["m00"], 1e-6))
    cY = int(M["m01"] / max(M["m00"], 1e-6))

    return cX, cY

def find_rectangles(img):
    filtered = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 1), dtype=np.uint8) 
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    for gray in cv2.split(img):
      for thrs in range(50, 200, 1):
          _retval, bin = cv2.threshold(gray, thrs, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
          contours, h = cv2.findContours(~bin, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
          contours = [contours[i] for i in range(len(contours)) if h[0][i][3] == -1]
          for cnt in contours:
              cnt_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
              poly = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cnt_len, True)
              w, h = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)[1]
              if len(poly) <= 8 and cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10 and cv2.contourArea(poly) < 1000 and (h / w) > 5:
                cv2.drawContours(filtered, [cnt], -1, 255, -1)

    return filtered

def dist(p1, p2):
  return math.sqrt((p1[0] - p2[0]) **2 + (p1[1] - p2[1]) ** 2)  

def findBarCodes(image):

  thresh = find_rectangles(image)
  contours, h = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
  contours = sorted([contours[i] for i in range(len(contours)) if h[0][i][3] == -1], key = lambda x: cv2.boundingRect(x)[0])

  groups = []

  for cnt in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    center_1 = get_center(cnt)
    found = False
    if w * h > 50 and w * h < thresh.shape[0] * thresh.shape[1] / 2:
      for group in groups:
        x2, y2, w2, h2 = cv2.boundingRect(group[-1])
        center_2 = get_center(group[-1])
        if abs(center_1[1] - center_2[1]) < 20 and (abs(h - h2) / max(h, h2)) < 0.3 and any(map(lambda p: dist((x, y), p) < 20, [(x2, y2), (x2 + w2, y2), (x2, y2 + h2), (x2 + w2, y2 + h2)])):
          group.append(cnt)
          found = True
          break
      if not found:
        groups.append([cnt])

  for group in groups[:]:
    mn = 1000000
    total = 0
    for c in group:
      x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
      total += w * h
      mn = min(mn, w * h)
    estimatedBars = total / mn
    if estimatedBars < 10:
      groups.remove(group)

  for idx, group in enumerate(groups):
    boxes = []
    for c in group:
      x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
      boxes.append([x,y, x+w,y+h])
      cv2.rectangle(thresh, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255, 2)
      cv2.putText(thresh, str(idx), (x, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.9, 255, 2)
      cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 128, -1)

    boxes = np.asarray(boxes)

    left = np.min(boxes[:,0])
    top = np.min(boxes[:,1])
    right = np.max(boxes[:,2])
    bottom = np.max(boxes[:,3])

    cv2.rectangle(image, (left,top), (right,bottom), 255, 2)


  cv2_imshow(image)
  cv2_imshow(thresh)

findBarCodes(cv2.imread('tQp93.jpg'))
```

Results:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a better morphological operation and have a threshold on the size of the connected components. Here is the change I made to your code to catch all barcodes:

```
import numpy as np
#import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('D:/1.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ddepth = cv2.cv.CV_32F if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.CV_32F
gradX = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradY = cv2.Sobel(gray, ddepth=ddepth, dx=0, dy=1, ksize=-1)

gradient = cv2.subtract(gradX, gradY)
gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)

blurred = cv2.blur(gradient, (9, 9))

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 5))
blurred = cv2.erode(blurred, kernel, iterations = 4)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7, 1))
blurred = cv2.dilate(blurred, kernel, iterations = 4)

(_, thresh) = cv2.threshold(blurred, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (21, 7))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
closed = cv2.erode(closed, None, iterations = 4)
closed = cv2.dilate(closed, None, iterations = 4)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 5))
closed = cv2.dilate(closed, kernel, iterations = 4)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 1))
closed = cv2.erode(closed, kernel, iterations = 2)

cnts = cv2.findContours(closed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

for i in range(len(cnts)):
    if cv2.contourArea(cnts[i]) > 2000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, i, (0, 255, 0), 3)

cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: @SiddanthShaiva You should change the parameters(like kernel size or threshold values) to get the best for all. I don't have those other images so I can not tune these values.